# Customize Visual Studio Add New Item

Tags: .net, visual-studio

The forms which I create in visual studio are usually in right to left layout with Tahoma font but when I create new WinForm, it's left to right and the font is Microsoft Sans Serif.

How can I create new Item in "Add new item" Window which is right to left and customized with settings I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247121.aspx) for information about customizing item templates.